# Line is not starting from previous day high in TradingView Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Expectation:
Plotting previous day high is an easy task.
But the following code is written to get previous day high and if todays close is crossed the previous day high line it should break high line at that point.

Issue:
The yellow line is the high line. It starts from the previous bar index, not from previous day high bar index or from previous day start.

What I need:
The high line should start from previous day high point bar index or from previous day start.
Also please correct if there is any unnecessay codes written or any thing that can be simplified.

Picture:

[image]

Code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='HL', shorttitle='HL', overlay=true)

i_htf = 'D'
i_show_last = 1
i_ln_h_offset = 20
i_hide_crossed = true

[high_htf] = request.security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, timeframe=i_htf, expression=[high[1]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

// Check if the current bar breaks a price level
break_line(price) =>
    (close[1] < price and close >= price) or (close[1] > price and close <= price)

var float last_high = na
var int last_index = na

var line[] keep_lines = array.new_line()
var line[] all_lines = array.new_line()

if barstate.isconfirmed
    _line = line.new(x1=last_index, y1=last_high, x2=bar_index + 10, y2=last_high, color=#ffff00)

    array.push(all_lines, _line)
    if array.size(all_lines) > i_show_last
        removed_line = array.shift(all_lines)
        if array.includes(keep_lines, removed_line)
            index_of_removed_line = array.indexof(keep_lines, removed_line)
            array.remove(keep_lines, index_of_removed_line)
        line.delete(removed_line)

    last_high := high_htf
    last_index := bar_index

// Check if the current bar breaks the line
for current_line in all_lines
    if array.includes(keep_lines, current_line)
        continue
    line.set_x2(current_line, bar_index + i_ln_h_offset)
    line_price = line.get_y1(current_line)
    if break_line(line_price)
        line.set_x2(current_line, bar_index)
        array.push(keep_lines, current_line)

// Remove crossed lines
for keep_line in keep_lines
    line_price = line.get_y1(keep_line)
    if i_hide_crossed and break_line(line_price)
        line.delete(keep_line)
        int index = array.indexof(all_lines, keep_line)
        if not na(index)
            array.remove(all_lines, index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is team effort by Sharad Gaikwad and me, we received this question about two days ago in the Telegram PineCoders Q&A section.
Sharad did build the structure and I added the repeating part.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500)

type UDT_lines
    line upper
    bool upper_extend = true
    line lower
    bool lower_extend = true

var historical_lines = array.new<UDT_lines>()

[prevDayHigh, prevDayLow, _time] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high[1], low[1], time[1]], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

var hi_today = 0.
var lo_today = 0.

int lines_back = input.int(3, "Max Historical Lines Back", 1, 250)

if(timeframe.change('D'))
    my_lines = UDT_lines.new()
    my_lines.upper := line.new(_time, prevDayHigh, time, prevDayHigh, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.green)
    my_lines.lower := line.new(_time, prevDayLow , time, prevDayLow , xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.red)
    historical_lines.unshift(my_lines)
    hi_today := high
    lo_today := low
    if historical_lines.size() > lines_back
        old_lines = historical_lines.pop()
        old_lines.upper.delete()
        old_lines.lower.delete()

hi_today := math.max(hi_today, high)
lo_today := math.min(lo_today, low)

for old_lines in historical_lines
    if hi_today < old_lines.upper.get_y1() and old_lines.upper_extend
        old_lines.upper.set_x2(time)
    else
        old_lines.upper_extend := false

    if lo_today > old_lines.lower.get_y1() and old_lines.lower_extend
        old_lines.lower.set_x2(time)
    else
        old_lines.lower_extend := false
```

You may have a look at the HowTo for [UDTs](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#user-defined-types) and [Arrays](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html).

Comment: Awesome. It met my expectations. I was trying to achieve this for a week.

Comment: I added a day counter which counts days as 3, 2, 1 to add as a label. "_time " plots from the start of the line, 'time' is plotting at the day end. How to move the label to the broken end point of the respective line like "___________2", "__________1". Or is there any better way.. Code/////////// var day_counter = 0 if(timeframe.change('D')) day_counter := day_counter + 1 label_text = str.tostring(lines_back - (day_counter - 1) % lines_back)

Comment: @Arun_K_Bhaskar update label position inside `if else` block where it says `old_lines.*_extend = false`. This is the position where lines stop extending. `old_lines.*.get_x1()` is your X-Position for the label